# Passcode in iOS with KKPassCodeLock

Tags: ios, passwords, appdelegate

I'm using in my application KKPassCodeLock classes and I already all set, the only thing I do not get is that once the password has been set out to launch the application. I searched a lot and I see that some people have the same problem but can not find the solution and do not know what could happen. My application starts with a tabBarController with 5 tabs.

According to the exemplary classes AppDelegate.h with the example should be configured with:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KKPasscodeLock.h"
#import "KKPasscodeViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,KKPasscodeViewControllerDelegate>

// contraseña de la aplicación
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// contraseña de la aplicación
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// contraseña de la aplicación

[[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock] setDefaultSettings];
[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock].eraseOption = YES;

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

RootViewController* vc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.window setRootViewController:_navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// contraseña de la aplicación
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
if ([[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock] isPasscodeRequired]) {
    KKPasscodeViewController *vc = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc.mode = KKPasscodeModeEnter;
    vc.delegate = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
            nav.navigationBar.opaque = NO;
        } else {
            nav.navigationBar.tintColor = _navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
            nav.navigationBar.translucent = _navigationController.navigationBar.translucent;
            nav.navigationBar.opaque = _navigationController.navigationBar.opaque;
            nav.navigationBar.barStyle = _navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;
        }

        [_navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
    });
}
}

// contraseña de la aplicación
- (void)shouldEraseApplicationData:(KKPasscodeViewController*)viewController
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Has ingresado incorrectamente la contraseña muchas veces. Todas las notas de tu base de datos han sido eliminadas." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
}

// contraseña de la aplicación
- (void)didPasscodeEnteredIncorrectly:(KKPasscodeViewController*)viewController
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Has ingresado incorrectamente la contraseña muchas veces." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}

@end
```

In the example application has to open a xib called RootViewController, but in my case should not be like me and leave it starts with a blank screen, which is the xib.

How I can configure it to start the password request and my tabBarController out instead of that xib?

Thank you very much!